# html button not worked and work wrong in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, button

I have design a custom button that I want to use on my html page but it's not worked

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("AddCategories/" + Model.Id, "test")">
        <button type="button">
            <a href="#" id="" class="btn">Add new things here</a>
        </button>
    </a>​
```

here is the code for check http://jsfiddle.net/YGCWZ/

Please someone can help me to do this.I got another thing that Firefox and chrome both do this wrong.

```
<a href="/test/AddCategories/1">dfdsf
        </a>
<button type="button"><a href="/test/AddCategories/1">
            </a><a href="#" id="" class="btn">Add new things here</a>
        </button>
```

Could someone help me to find out the way to do this link.

thanks

Comment: I would suggest using JavaScript to put a clickListener on the respective button instead of using the current `href` structure. Also,  what's the question?

Comment: Why have the hyperlink inside the button?  Looks like Chrome and Firefox are rendering directly what you've written, while IE is just choosing to remove the inner <a> tag. For usage, see: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/button and http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_button.asp

Comment: Could you explain what you except and what you get with that?

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 `button` element should not have a `href` like an anchor link. It's used to submit data from a form or as a standalone button, not to be used as a link.

If you're using a button only for the looks, I would stick with something simple like this and style it myself in CSS.

```
<a class="button" href="somewhere.html">My Link</a>
```

If you need some JavaScript in there, then either bind an event to it in your framework (eg. jQuery) or run the function directly, where `myFunc` should return `false` to avoid the default link behaviour:

```
<a class="button" href="javascript:myFunc();">My Link</a>
```

If you're using the button in a `form`, then you should be using the `onclick` attribute. Also, I don't think you should be nesting anchor tags.

EDIT:

For styling, you could build on this by adding background images and so forth:

```
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.button {
    font: bold 12px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

Comment: No. `<input>` belong to a form, `<button>` is independent element. If you can prove otherwise I'll be glad to read it. Also, `<button>` can nest elements inside it. [And it works perfectly fine](http://jsfiddle.net/YGCWZ/2/).

Comment: Yes, `<button>` can be used outside a form but can ref one: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#form-owner

Comment: Of course it *can* refer to a form, but your first sentence "The HTML5 button element **belongs in a form element**" is wrong. And the OP never put `href` in the button, just nested `<a>` element inside it which is also valid.